# Register phone as HID (mouse)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, bluetooth, device-driver, hid

Given a Windows Mobile 6.1 smartphone with Bluetooth I want to register it as a mouse.

Basically what I do now:

- Start the Bluetooth service on device with Guid {00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}
- Connect from desktop PC to device.

Result:

- Device is detected with all services including the HID one but there is no driver for it

Current workaround:

- Desktop application that connects to the bluetooth service and reads the data stream

Desired solution:

- Register the service as Bluetooth mouse and send mouse events from phone.

Q:

1. How do I get to the desired solution?
2. Do a I have to write an inf file for it?
3. I have to add extra information to the bluetooth service?
4. How can I send mouse clicks over this service?

Currently I am developing in C# using .NETCF 3.5 and Microsoft.WindowsMobile.SharedSource.Bluetooth assembly from .NET CF SDK but it would be no problem to work in C++ if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need drivers for HID.  While I haven't sent mouse clicks over bt, I have sent other strange things over the generic HID driver.  So:

- You shouldn't need a .inf file or new driver.
- Bluetooth is just your transport (wire replacement), so there "shouldn't" be extra work there either. Except for maybe pairing the two devices.
- Sending the clicks I believe is done by sending the properly shaped data packets to the PC.

Look at the linux code pointed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995929/hid-mouse-position-linux-kernel-source-code) for details of the packet.  And obviously you've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281081/making-a-windows-mobile-device-emulate-a-bluetooth-hid-device) for sending the data.

Have fun with NetCF!

Comment: Thank you for your response. However the device is recognized as HID but when Windows tries to install the driver for it I get a warning. I would like this to not happen

Comment: You may need to set the device type/id that windows recognizes and can use the generic HID driver.  This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms923723.aspx

Comment: As for as I see there must be a SDP Report associated with the connection. So I need to provide the HID Guid and a SDP description. But I don't know how to write that :(

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to provide a valid SDP is to use the SPD of an existing Bluetooth mouse.